# What's the fastest way for counting words in a large dataset using R?

Tags: r, mapreduce, bigdata

I have an SQL database with 7 million+ records, each record containing some text. Within each record I want to perform text analysis, say count the occurences of specific words. I've tried R's `tokenize` function within the `openNLP` package which works great for small files, but 7 million records * between 1-100 words per record gets too large for R to hold in a `data.frame`. I thought about using R's `bigmemory` or `ff` packages, or even the `mapReduce` package. Do you guys have a preferred approach or package for this type of analysis?

Comment: count the number of spaces + 1? You could probably use some vectorised operations like `gsub` to replace the entire character vector with "" except for spaces and then count with `nchar`? Of course this is just a method. I wonder if your problem is method or loading it into R...

Comment: Do you have to read in the whole dataset at once? Why not using `strsplit(...," ")` on each single entry?

Comment: @Arun - I actually want to count the occurence of certain words, not just count the number of words. Updated my question.

Comment: But if you want to count the occurrence of a certain word, I think you could do that on the SQL side still using the `like`operator, or does it require there too much CPU power? And once you have the subset of rows, you could send this one to R (Or finish the whole job on the SQL side).

Comment: Why not do the searches in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe approach it in parallel.  I used `parLapply` b/c I believe it works on all three OS.

```
wc <- function(x) length(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+")))

wordcols <- rep("I like icecream alot.", 100000)

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()))
clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("wc", "wordcols"), envir=environment())
output <- parLapply(cl, wordcols, function(x) {
        wc(x)
    }
)
stopCluster(cl)  
sum(unlist(output))
```

Comment: Why parallel? It is extremely fast without parallelism. `system.time(o <- sapply(strsplit(wordcols, "[ ]+"), length))` takes 0.45 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: I actually want to count the occurence of specific words (updated my question). So wouldn't I need `wordcols` to hold my entire dataset before applying your method (which is very interesting by the way)? I can store the data in SQL easily enough, but reading it into R via RODBC (what I currently do) breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

On the SQL side you could extract also for each entry the `len`, then apply a `replace(" yourWord ","")` (with flanking spaces...) to it, calculate again the total string length and then take the differences between those two, that should do the trick. My SQL skills are not so well that I could present here easily an running example, sorry for that...